# Bluetooth auto connect shows no output device

Tags: linux, systemd, raspbian, pulseaudio, bluetooth

I've manage to follow a bunch of other threads like this one: [How to set up automatic connection of bluetooth headset?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334386/how-to-set-up-automatic-connection-of-bluetooth-headset) and read up on [Bluetooth#Auto_power-on_after_boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth#Auto_power-on_after_boot) and added the user to the right group. Which has given me good auto-connection on boot.

The problem is that `pacmd list-sinks` show only one sink and it's the built in audio output. running `bluetoothctl` shows that the device is connected.

I do however get this in the journal:

```
Process '/usr/sbin/th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev' failed with exit code 1.
```

If I use `bluetoothctl` to disconnect and reconnect the device, it comes up as a output source. I could write a bash script that sets everything up, but I would really like for this `systemd` + `bluetooth.service` to work.

Any ideas on what to do and why the sound card isn't coming up at boot?

(It's a RaspberryPi 4 with raspbian)

Comment: Before the first connection, does the 'show' command in bluetoothctl show sinks and/or srces registered?

Comment: Could be a *timing* issue: some service (maybe PA) starts too much early than bluetooth service