# Bluez: Bluetooth Auto connection not working

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_headset

I have followed the arch wiki guide and this is what I am getting on my bluetooth shell when I fire up my bluetooth headset.

```bsh
[CHG] Device <My MAC> Connected: yes
[CHG] Device <My MAC> Connected: no
```

Comment: Is it trusted?  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/371801/143394

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Happens for me also (Arch Linux with newest Kernel), even though the device is trusted!